# <picture> tag in HTML5 not working on chrome?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsive HTML sites</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <picture>
        <source srcset="marbled.jpg" media= "(max-width: 600px)">
        <source srcset="rolemodel.jpg" media= "(max-width: 1400px)">
        <source srcset="supalonely.jpg">
    </picture>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code and when I run it on chrome, there are no warnings or display. All the images are in the same folder and when I add img before source, it shows all the images, instead of showing it according to device-width

Comment: First I would fix the meta tag. `<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` is invalid and must be broken into 2 separate meta tags. I'm not sure this solves your problem, but is a good start.

Comment: I separated the values charset and name/content into 2 different meta tags and also added img src, so now it works fine for me. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to add an `<img>` along with the sources. Link to more on [`<picture>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp).

Example code below will change image on screen re-size. Hope this helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsive HTML sites</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        source, img{
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <picture>
        <source srcset="https://9to5google.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/03/google-images-material-theme.jpg?quality=82&strip=all&w=1600" media= "(max-width: 600px)">
        <source srcset="https://dg.imgix.net/do-you-think-you-re-happy-jgdbfiey-en/landscape/do-you-think-you-re-happy-jgdbfiey-9bb0198eeccd0a3c3c13aed064e2e2b3.jpg?ts=1520525855&ixlib=rails-4.0.1&auto=format%2Ccompress&fit=min&w=700&h=394&dpr=2&ch=Width%2CDPR" media= "(max-width: 800px)">
        <img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png">
    </picture>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem. Go ahead and park this as answered if you don't have any more questions. Glad I could help